# pygame.mixer.Sound - Unable to open file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I almost have my sample game, which is my avoider game, set up, the game runs excellent with and without background music, however, when I try to add the gameover sound, python complains with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dodger.py", line 53, in <module>
    gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.mp3')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'gameover.mp3'
```

The code is the following:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 1800
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1000
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60
BADDIEMINSIZE = 10
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 40
BADDIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 1
PLAYERMOVERATE = 3

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.mp3')


# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0


    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }

            baddies.append(newBaddie)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

I have researched online and no luck, please help! Assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a valid mp3 file named `gameover.mp3` in the same directory as your program .py file? If you try loading `player.png` before `gameover.mp3` does it give a similar not-found error?

Comment: Looks like this error is triggered by a [corrupt file](https://github.com/xamox/pygame/blob/master/src/mixer.c#L1698), not a missing one

Comment: Yes, I do have it and also, no, the game runs excellent with no audio, including the images

Comment: The file, by the way, runs fine on windows media player.

Comment: I think you need your files in a `.wav` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/xamox/pygame/blob/master/src/mixer.c#L1684) of `Sound.__init__`, the code ends up calling [`Mix_LoadWAV_RW`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_20.html), which:

> Load[s] `src` for use as a sample. This can load WAVE, AIFF, RIFF, OGG, and VOC formats.

Note that this does not list MP3 as a valid format

The [`pygame` docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) have this to say:

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV.

Comment: `ogg` is probably a better choice, compression-wise

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound):

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV.

From the documentation for [`mixer.music`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html):

> Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead.

Basically, Pygame doesn't handle the MP3 format. Use OGG files.